# Adding values from a specified date range

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file with two columns: Date and Value.

What is the best way to import the data, specify a date range and out put the value sum of that date range?

[Example excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngsrT.png)

StartDate = 23.09.2020

EndDate = 26.09.2020

Desired output:
197.03

Comment: Please add example data into the question for future reference, rather than posting a link to an external source. At some point, the link can expire.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your data csv looks like this:
my_data.csv

```
Date,Value
01-02-2021 00:00:00,75.68
02-02-2021 00:00:00,84.73
03-02-2021 00:00:00,15.25
04-02-2021 00:00:00,20.00
05-02-2021 00:00:00,81.05
```

and codes to handle it: Python3.6 with pandas==1.1.4

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv', encoding='utf-8', header=0)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

start_date = datetime.strptime("02.02.2021", "%d.%m.%Y")
end_date = datetime.strptime("03.02.2021", "%d.%m.%Y")

selected_df = df[(df['Date'] >= start_date) & (df['Date'] <= end_date)]
total = selected_df['Value'].sum()

print(selected_df)
print(total)
```

the output is:

```
        Date  Value
1 2021-02-02  84.73
2 2021-02-03  15.25
99.98
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is in an Excel file in the same format as the image, including the 2nd row.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_excel('table.xlsx', header=0, parse_dates=True)
df.drop(index=0,inplace=True)
df['Date and time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date and time'], format='%d.%m.%Y')

StartDate = datetime.strptime('23.09.2021', '%d.%m.%Y')

EndDate = datetime.strptime('26.09.2021', '%d.%m.%Y')

total_kWh = df[(df['Date and time']>=StartDate) & (df['Date and time']<=EndDate)]['Total system'].sum()

print(total_kWh)
```